# Do local files remain accessible offline?

Tags: s3fs

If I mount a local directory and point it to an S3 bucket using s3fs, does it eventually receive the files stored in S3 and do the files remain accessible for reading even if S3 or internet is not accessible?
Is there an alternative to s3fs that can serve the above requirement if s3fs does not serve it?

Answer (score 0):

s3fs is not intended as an offline file system.  However, metadata (`-o max_stat_cache_size`, `-o stat_cache_expire`) and data caching (`-o use_cache`) may allow s3fs to work offline in a limited capacity.

[catfs](https://github.com/kahing/catfs) also has an [open issue](https://github.com/kahing/catfs/issues/41) requesting offline support although this is not implemented.